# PostgreSQL: How to extract all available latest data grouped without self-joining?

Tags: postgresql

Users submit forms, so I have the forms table:

```
date        user  name  phone
2016-01-01  1     NULL  1234
2016-02-02  1     NULL  5678
2016-03-03  1     John  NULL
2016-04-04  2     Ken   NULL
```

I'd like to get all available latest user data grouped by user:

```
user  name  phone
1     John  5678
2     Ken   NULL
```

If the user has entered different data for the same field – I'd like to get the latest.

For example – user 1 submitted phone 1234, then submitted 5678 – so I need 5678 only.

Is it possible to get the result using PostgreSQL single query without self-joins and sub-queries? Some combination of aggregation functions?

P.S. This is why the question differs from similar: The simple "distinct on" doesn't help because it gives last values even if they are nulls.

Comment: This is why the question differs from similar: The simple "distinct on" doesn't help because it gives last values even if they are nulls

Comment: Sorry, missed your requirement for latest in cols, not latest row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `first_value()` over the order which gives non-null values first:

```
with my_table (date, user_id, name, phone) as (
values
    ('2016-01-01',  1,     NULL, '1234'),
    ('2016-02-02',  1,     NULL, '5678'),
    ('2016-03-03',  1,     'John', NULL),
    ('2016-04-04',  2,     'Ken', NULL),
    ('2016-02-05',  3,     NULL, NULL),
    ('2016-03-06',  3,     'Susan', '4444'),
    ('2016-04-07',  3,     'Alice', '5555')
)

select distinct on (user_id)
    user_id, 
    first_value(name) over (partition by user_id order by name is null, date desc) as name,
    first_value(phone) over (partition by user_id order by phone is null, date desc) as phone
from my_table
order by user_id, date desc

 user_id | name  | phone 
---------+-------+-------
       1 | John  | 5678
       2 | Ken   | 
       3 | Alice | 5555
(3 rows)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select
    usr, name, phone
from (
    select
        usr, name,
        row_number() over (partition by usr order by date desc) rn,
        first_value(phone) over (
            partition by usr
            order by case when phone is null 
                then 1 else 0 end, date desc
        ) phone
    from your_table t
) t where rn = 1;
```

`row_number` to assign row number in the order of date within each user to get the latest row by filtering and `first_value` with conditional order by to get latest non null phone number. Also, similar logic can be applied to name to get the latest non null value column if needed.

Comment: It's better than self-joins. Thank you!